# Running shellscript with cronjob is making problems, executing manually not. Ideas?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, cron

I made a shell script called `/home/root/cron_grads.sh` (chmodded 755) on my server.

In this directory are more grads-scripts like `500hPa_p0.gs` (644). My main script creates a temporary file `grads_exec.gs`, fills it with some content and then tries to copy the content of `500hPa_p0.gs` onto the end of it before executing the whole thing This works fine, even on the server if I start it manually.

But using `crontab -e` with:

```
42 0,6,12,18 * * * /home/root/grads/cron_grads.sh
```

... an error occurs. The script starts but grads says:

```
cat: 500hPa_p0.gs: File or directory not found
```

I am using bash in `cron_grads.sh` with `#!/bin/bash` at the top in it. `crontab -e` also contains `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue within your `cron_grads.sh` script. When you call it manually, I assume you're in `/home/root` so it would run something like:

```
echo test > grads_exec.gs
cat 500hPa_p0.gs >> grads_exec.gs
```

But if you ran that from while at `/home/oli/`, it would attempt to write to `/home/oli/grads_exec.gs` and read from `/home/oli/500hPa_p0.gs`. That's why cat is blowing up in your case.

To fix, either explicitly cd into the right directory (and use an absolute path):

```
cd /home/root
echo test > grads_exec.gs
cat 500hPa_p0.gs >> grads_exec.gs
```

Or use absolute paths everywhere:

```
echo test > /home/root/grads_exec.gs
cat /home/root/500hPa_p0.gs >> /home/root/grads_exec.gs
```

Or for safety's sake, both.

Comment: Well, thank you very much, a cd /home/root/grads did it. You helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use absolute path for all your commands or get the PATH variable as here:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user